# replace quotes on all files

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I want to replace all strings without string interpolation that uses double quote into single quote

for example:

```
<?php
require_once $__CFG_dir_lib . "systemconfiguration.php";
require_once $__CFG_dir_lib . "lib.php";
$bla = "test $a 123";
$x = '<a href="123">test</a>';
$y = "<a href='123'>\ntest</a>";
```

into:

```
<?php
require_once $__CFG_dir_lib . 'systemconfiguration.php';
require_once $__CFG_dir_lib . 'lib.php';
$bla = "test $a 123";
$x = '<a href="123">test</a>';
$y = "<a href='123'>\ntest</a>";
```

who can i do this using IntelliJ without clicking one by one [image]

what i've tried was:

```
find: "([^"'$\\]+)"
replace: '\$1'
```

but it still replaces the `$x` example

Answer (score 1):

**Possible in Notepad++ (and any other editor that uses Perl or PCRE)**

I notice you're doing this in a text editor. In most editors, it's going to be very hard. In an editor that uses the `PCRE` engine, we can do it like this:

**Search:** `'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|"((?:(?!\$\w)[^"'])*)"`

**Replace:** `'$1'`

In the [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/uZ1xN5/1), look at the substitutions in the bottom pane.

Comment: Hey Kokkizu, if this is an option, let me know and I'll add an explanation and references. :)

Comment: thanks, but no, i'm not using Windows ^^ (Linux user)

Comment: oh wait, maybe i could use `find` and `perl`